# Tablet can not auto-rotate when connect external monitor (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: multiple-monitors, tablet

My tablet can auto-rotate normally.
The panel will become original orientation after connect external monitor using VGA, and the auto-rotate would be invalid.
There is no orientation setting for Built-in display in Settings->Devices->Displays, but I can use "xrandr --output DSI-1 --rotate right" to change the orientation.
Can I enable the auto-rotate function even if connect to external monitor?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu do you have on your tablet ?

Comment: Which monitor are you using and what is the connection type?

Comment: @SorenA: Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: @Yaron, external monitor vandor: NEX, product: 22VD; use VGA port; what is connection type? the connector in monitors.xml is "DP-1"

Comment: I highly doubt it's possible because if `iio-sensor-proxy` doesn't recognize the orientation (accelerometer) sensor it won't work, unless you want to rotate the tablet screen and configuring it to rotate the VGA monitor. Try launching `monitor-sensor`, it will give you some insights about what's possible and what's not and how does the kernel interprets the rotation events.

Comment: @Yaron, "monitor-sensor" indicates the Accelermeter can detect the orientation of tablet, but the auto-rotate does not work when connect external monitor.

Comment: @ZeusChen So you're saying that attaching an external monitor disables the ability to rotate the tablet display?

Comment: @Yaron, It disable the ability to auto-rotate the tablet display. I still can use "xrandr --output DSI-1 --rotate right" to rotate the tablet display.

Comment: The element which actually controls the rotation is the GNOME rotation plugin, there are several relevant keys you need to check:
`gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.orientation active true` or `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchscreen orientation-lock false`.  

Please run these when the external monitor is connected and reply with your conclusions.

Comment: @Yaron, the auto-rotate still doesn't work...

Comment: Have you tried it while running `monitor-sensor`?

Comment: @Yaron, monitor-sensor can detect the accelerometer orientation changed, but auto-rotate still doesn't work.

Comment: All I can tell from reading the `iio-sensor-proxy` is that the rotation is done either by GNOME polling the service or `geoclue` but nothing further, there are ways to debug also, maybe it can solve this issue: https://github.com/hadess/iio-sensor-proxy